# How to disable POST request method in Websphere plugin-cfg.xml

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

Usually, request methods (like TRACE, OPTIONS etc) can be disabled on the Webserver level (IHS, nginx). But I need to disable, or even enable, specific request methods on the Websphere/plugin-cfg.xml level. Is this possible in an automated way (no manual editing of the plugin-cfg.xml file, either via console or a script)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't block HTTP methods in the WAS WebServer Plug-in.  But since it runs in a webserver, you're free to configure any behavior you like at that layer -- or in your application itself.